# How to integrate jBPM workflow with Spring Boot using RESTful end points?

Tags: java, spring-boot, workflow, jbpm

I'm trying to integrate a jBPM workflow with Spring Boot with RESTful endpoints. I got to know the usage of jBPM workflow using core Java with the help of examples provided in jBPM zip and few online sites.

But I'm unable to find the code of starting, moving and closing the jBPM workflow using the RESTful endpoints (with will be communicated with AngularJS front-end).

Answer (score 0):

[This repository](https://github.com/karlnicholas/business-application) contains one of the jBPM starter applications from [jBPM - Build your business application](https://start.jbpm.org/) expanded to demonstrate more complete examples.

Part I: In order to create and test a simple script I created two projects by copying the respective original-business-application-* projects.

Part II: A next logical step to creating a Springboot based jBPM API is to create a simple Hello, World API.

Part III: A Springboot application runs in docker very well and so runs in the cloud very well. This capability is added by default to the jBPM sample applications.

It's still a work in progress but I think it is the starting point you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have not mentioned which version of jBPM you are using so assuming you are using jBPM6. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch17.html).
"starting, moving and closing the jBPM workflow" are all different steps which we will discuss here.

1. Before 'starting' workflows, you need to create .bpmn file and upload it to jBPM server. This is called deployment. Once deployment exists on server, deploy deployment using this [section](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch17.html#_deployment_call_details). e.g 
   http://host:port/jbpm-console/rest/deployment//deploy
2. Once deployment is done, process instance needs to be created means process needs to be started. Refer this [section](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch17.html#remote.rest.runtime).  e.g.  /runtime/{deploymentId}/process/{processDefId}/start
3. Once instance is started, task level operations can be done with help of this [section](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch17.html#remote.rest.task). This constitutes to 'moving' of workflow.
4. 'closing' workflow is again process level API. Workflow/Process instance is aborted means closed. e.g. /runtime/{deploymentId}/process/instance/{procInstId+}/abort

Please let me know if you have any doubts.